# need to modify an if statement to exclude or allow multiple manufacturers_name

Tags: php, zen-cart

I am having a problem with this part:

```
&& ($manufacturers_name) == FloorDot
```

How would I either exclude or even allow Certain multiple manufacturers names?

Example:

```
if(zen_products_lookup((int)$_GET['products_id'], 'products_price') <= 199 && ($manufacturers_name) == FloorDot, Crain, SFIFloors, ETC $$ (Here i would want to exclude) == certain Products, ETC ||
```

Here is original Code:

```
<!--bof free ship icon  -->
<?php if(zen_get_product_is_always_free_shipping($products_id_current) &&                 $flag_show_product_info_free_shipping) { ?>
<div id="freeShippingIcon"><?php echo TEXT_PRODUCT_FREE_SHIPPING_ICON; ?></div>
```

Here is new Code:

```
<!--bof free ship icon2  -->
<?php if(zen_products_lookup((int)$_GET['products_id'], 'products_price') <= 199 &&         ($product_weight) <=20 && ($manufacturers_name) == FloorDot ||    zen_get_product_is_always_free_shipping($products_id_current) &&    $flag_show_product_info_free_shipping) { ?>
<div id="freeShippingIcon2"><?php echo TEXT_PRODUCT_FREE_SHIPPING_ICON2; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<!--eof free ship icon2  -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array):

```
$valid_mfgrs= array("FooCorp", "BarInc", "PopCo");
if ( in_array($manufacturers_name, $valid_mfgrs) ) {
    // The mfgr. name is one of the valid mfgrs.
}
```

Comment: <!--bof free ship icon2  -->
<?php if(zen_products_lookup((int)$_GET['products_id'], 'products_price') <= 199 && ($product_weight) <=20 && ($manufacturers_name) == FloorDot || zen_get_product_is_always_free_shipping($products_id_current) && $flag_show_product_info_free_shipping) { ?>
<div id="freeShippingIcon2"><?php echo TEXT_PRODUCT_FREE_SHIPPING_ICON2; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<!--eof free ship icon2  -->

Comment: how would i add that to this

Comment: Wow. Don't post code in comments - it's completely unreadable. If you must include more/new code, post it in the original question.